# Unable to access Pop Up / iframe window using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I'm pretty new to selenium. I'm working on a autocheckout scrip using selenium python. Script executes very smooth till the final checkout page. However, I'm unable to access element on the final page('Razorpay Checkout'), which is a kind of pop up/iframe window.
Any help accessing the same would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Below is the code I'm using

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/hamhatre/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://shopatsc.com/collections/playstation-5/products/ps5-horizon-forbidden-west")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pincode_input"]')
elem.send_keys("400708")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="check-delivery-submit"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[3]/div/button[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_email"]').send_keys('abc@gmail.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_first_name"]').send_keys('abc')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_last_name"]').send_keys('xyz')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_address1"]').send_keys('Rd1, Flat no 2, Apt 1')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_address2"]')).send_keys('Nothing')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_city"]').send_keys('Mumbai')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_province"]').send_keys('Maharashtra')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_zip"]').send_keys('400708')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_phone_custom"]').send_keys('9876543210')

driver.find_element_by_id('continue_to_shipping_button_custom').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('continue_button').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/main/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/button').click()


print(driver.title)
seq = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print(seq)
print("No of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))


for index in range(len(seq)):
    iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[index]
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    driver.find_element_by_id('language-dropdown').click()
```

Below is the error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\hamhatre\Desktop\Algotron\WebScrap_Sample.py", line 47, in <module>
driver.find_element_by_id('language-dropdown').click()

File "C:\Users\hamhatre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)

File "C:\Users\hamhatre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {

File "C:\Users\hamhatre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "C:\Users\hamhatre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="language-dropdown"]"}
(Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.84)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using chromedriver version 100. Your code throws a `NoSuchElementException`. Thats because your driver tries to find an element which does not exist. So, what you need to do is to put `time.sleep(4)` statements after your `click()` statements (Your browser needs time to open the window/s). If you are done using the driver, use `driver.quit()`.

Followed code worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/hamhatre/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://shopatsc.com/collections/playstation-5/products/ps5-horizon-forbidden-west")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pincode_input"]')
elem.send_keys("400708")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="check-delivery-submit"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[3]/div/button[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_email"]').send_keys('abc@gmail.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_first_name"]').send_keys('abc')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_last_name"]').send_keys('xyz')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_address1"]').send_keys('Rd1, Flat no 2, Apt 1')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_address2"]')).send_keys('Nothing')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_city"]').send_keys('Mumbai')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_province"]').send_keys('Maharashtra')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_zip"]').send_keys('400708')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_phone_custom"]').send_keys('9876543210')

driver.find_element_by_id('continue_to_shipping_button_custom').click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_id('continue_button').click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/main/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/button').click()
time.sleep(4)


print(driver.title)
seq = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print(seq)
print("No of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))


for index in range(len(seq)):
    iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[index]
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    driver.find_element_by_id('language-dropdown').click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, @JAdel!
Your proposed solution works really well!
Just a quick question, I've already introduced 'driver.implicitly_wait(20)' in my code, why is it not adding any value(in terms of giving the browser enough time to open the window/s)? Is there anything else I'm missing?
Thanks again for the solution!

Comment: This may help you https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html. There is a difference between ``explicit waits`` and ``implicit waits``.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could do in your next project:

- Use `WebDriverWait` to allow enough time for elements to be loaded
- Use `switch_to.default_content()` before switching to another frame
- Use time.sleep() while you switch frames
- Try using relative xpaths (ex: `//div[@id="user_address"]`). It's easy to right click and copy the absolute xpath for an element from the inspect window, however if there's another element added in between, your xpath would no longer point to the desired element. Moreover, relative xpaths would empower you with a deeper understanding allowing you to easily find elements.

This code should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D://chromedriver/100/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://shopatsc.com/collections/playstation-5/products/ps5-horizon-forbidden-west")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)


wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="pincode_input"]'))).send_keys('400708')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@id="check-delivery-submit"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[normalize-space(text())="Buy Now"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="checkout_email"]'))).send_keys('abc@gmail.com')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="checkout_shipping_address_first_name"]'))).send_keys('abc')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="checkout_shipping_address_last_name"]'))).send_keys('xyz')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="checkout_shipping_address_address1"]'))).send_keys('Rd1, Flat no 2, Apt 1')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="checkout_shipping_address_address2"]'))).send_keys('Nothing')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="checkout_shipping_address_city"]'))).send_keys('Mumbai')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[@id="checkout_shipping_address_province"]'))).send_keys('Maharashtra')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="checkout_shipping_address_zip"]'))).send_keys('400708')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="checkout_shipping_address_phone_custom"]'))).send_keys('9876543210')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="continue_to_shipping_button_custom"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="continue_button"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[normalize-space(text())="Complete order"]/parent::button'))).click()


print(driver.title)

# finding all iframes
iframes = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
print(f'No. of iframes: {len(iframes)}')

print('Looping through frames to check language dropdown')

found = False
frameno = 0
tries = 1
maxtries = 5
# Attempt at least 5 times to click on the language dropdown
while not found and frameno < len(iframes) and tries <= maxtries:
    try:
        print(f"Frame# {frameno} \t {tries} of {maxtries} tries")
        print('Switching to frame')
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[frameno])
        time.sleep(2)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="language-dropdown"]/div/div'))).click()
        found = True
        print('Found and clicked')
        
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        print("Exception occured. Capturing iframes again")
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        iframes = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Couldn't find/click on the language dropdown")
        frameno += 1
        
    finally:
        print('Switching to default content')
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        time.sleep(2)
        tries += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for recreating the entire code, @Shine J!

Comment: The above code works very well with a small addition of explicit time.sleep(4) just before the while loop.
I highly appreciate your time and efforts spent on the mentioned issue.
Thanks again!